# ADF Java Desktop Application Jar

Tags: java, swing, jar, desktop-application, oracle-adf

I have made an ADF Java desktop app, and put all the swing classes in the model.
It runs correctly from Jdevloper.
I access the application module using this way:

```
private static String amDef = "model.AppModule";
private static String config = "AppModuleLocal";
appModule = (AppModuleImpl)Configuration.createRootApplicationModule (amDef,config);
```

But, when i deploy it as a jar file and run it, it first runs well, but as soon as it accesses the application module it gives the following exception:

```
oracle.jbo.ConfigException: JBO-33003: Connection name MyConnection is not defined.
    at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.initializeFromConnectionName(Configuration.java:1199)
    at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:648)
    at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.PoolMgr.loadConfiguration(PoolMgr.java:605)
    at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.PoolMgr.findPool(PoolMgr.java:526)
    at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(Configuration.java:1505)
    at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(Configuration.java:1482)
    at classes.ImageCaptureAndPrint.actionPerformed(ImageCaptureAndPrint.java:888)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicRootPaneUI$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicRootPaneUI.java:208)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1663)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
    at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(KeyboardManager.java:307)
    at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(KeyboardManager.java:250)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(JComponent.java:2974)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2966)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6310)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Your code appears to have no relevance to your problem, which appears to be a database connection problem. The exception tells you the line in your ActionListener that is throwing the exception, and perhaps you should look critically at it.

Comment: this line calls the create root application module function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution

it was to create an ADF Library Jar File in the deployment in the model, it had the database connection by default.